# Unity + Firebase: Unable to load DLL 'FirebaseCppApp-10_3_0'

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, crashlytics

I am using Unity 2021.3.11f1 to implement Firebase 10.3.0 Analytics + Crashlytics for an Android Game.
After a few tests without anything showing up in the Google Dashboard, I figured something was wrong with the Firebase initializing.

As soon as I launch the game on my Android device, this is one of the first things seen in logcat:

```
01-05 15:51:45.078 32211  2657 E Unity   : DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FirebaseCppApp-10_3_0'. Tried the load the following dynamic libraries: Unable to load dynamic library 'FirebaseCppApp-10_3_0' because of 'Failed to open the requested dynamic library (0x06000000) dlerror() = dlopen failed: library "FirebaseCppApp-10_3_0" not found
01-05 15:51:45.078 32211  2657 E Unity   :   at Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper.SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_AppUtil (Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate applicationDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate arithmeticDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate divideByZeroDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate indexOutOfRangeDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate invalidCastDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate invalidOperationDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+ExceptionDelegate ioDelegate, Firebase.AppUtilPINVOKE+SWIGExceptionHelper+E
```

Here is what my Android Libraries with dependencies looks like:
(NB: At this point I tried installing Firebase 9.6.0 instead, that's why it doesn't say 10.3.0 here)

```
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each { project ->
    project.repositories {
        def unityProjectPath = $/file:///**DIR_UNITYPROJECT**/$.replace("\\", "/")
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url (unityProjectPath + "/Assets/Firebase/m2repository") // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:18, Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22, Assets/Firebase/Editor/CrashlyticsDependencies.xml:20
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:17
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.0' // Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.assetdelivery/Editor/Dependencies.xml:3
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.0' // Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.core/Editor/Dependencies.xml:3
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.1.1' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/CrashlyticsDependencies.xml:15
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-unity:9.6.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AnalyticsDependencies.xml:18
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-app-unity:9.6.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:22
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:20.1.2' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/AppDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk:18.2.13' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/CrashlyticsDependencies.xml:13
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-unity:9.6.0' // Assets/Firebase/Editor/CrashlyticsDependencies.xml:20
}
android {
  packagingOptions {
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/armeabi-v7a/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/mips64/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86/*' + '*')
      exclude ('/lib/x86_64/*' + '*')
  }
```

I run the usual 'CheckAndFixDependencies' and do not get any errors during this. I've also managed to get this working before in another project without problems, but no matter what I do it seems like the 'Core' app of firebase won't start due to not being able to find the DLL.

I tried both Firebase SDK 10.3.0 and 9.6.0 with the same results.

When I find the DLL that it claims to be missing in Unity (Assets/Firebase/Plugins/x86_64/FirebaseCppApp-9_6_0.dll) it stands as being included in every platform, Editor as well as standalone.

I've forced countless amounts of dependency resolves, without luck.

I tried disabling the target architecture ARMv7 (Because I saw someone suggesting it in another post about this). No help either unfortunately.

I'm currently testing with apk so I don't have to work through aab atm, but I really doubt that should cause Firebase issues.

Am I missing something extremely obvious / being blind here?

Comment: Could you check if you have different versions of the same dll ?
You can also check the dll import settings to see if they are set as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I will try many tries but it isn't work.
At the end of the second day, I have tried create a new empty project and add it from
https://developers.google.com/unity/archive#firebase_app_core

in package manager as tarball tgz files:

1. external dependency tgz
2. firebase app (core) tgz
3. for me its firebase analytics for you its another firebase tgz

Those tgz must be the same version in my case first install 10.3 it isn't work.
Second i download 9.6 tgz files. And it's working.

But I have a new error in the console: Database URL not set in the Firebase config.

It's solved in firebase account you need to create realtime database, and downloaded the new google-services.json. Then in Unity remove old google-services.json and clean Assets\StreamingAssets folder. Import new google-services.json. And it worked.

Then I tried in my work project. I remove all firebase sdk folders and did the same. And its works fine!

Comment: Install Like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJRZOAA63aA

Comment: Database url: https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database